# Android - Full text search using existing database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, full-text-search

I've looked around for tutorials and documentation on how to implement full text search in Android. However, most of the tutorials assume that you are creating and populating a SQLite database when the application loads.

For my application, I already have a pre-loaded database (i.e. it's stored in the assets folder and then copied over when the application first runs) - how would I go about creating Virtual Tables in such a situation?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: See the following link - http://blog.andresteingress.com/2011/09/30/android-quick-tip-using-sqlite-fts-tables/

It uses "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " and then populates them and performs a search using these VIRTUAL tables - but if I already have an existing database, how would I do this?

Comment: Why do you have to create a virtual table if you already have a table in your prepopulated database? Why can't you just read from your prepopulated database?

Comment: As far as I am aware FTS only works with Virtual Tables - or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE` and `INSERTS` can be applied to the pre-loaded database the same as a normal table. The database will then need to be re-packaged.